# fix image size without re-sizing

Tags: image, html, image-processing, resize, slideshow

I have a `div` which is `width:500px;` and `height:170px;`

The `div` contains a **jquery** slideshow which gets random images from my database and displays them.

Problem is that the images are uploaded by users and can be any **aspect-ratio**/**any size**.

I need the images to fit the `div` without being resized using

```
style='height:x; width:x;
```

Basically, I want all images to be displayed properly and in acutal quality.

I don't want to restrict which sizes of images can be uploaded as they as displayed in other parts of the site in full size/quality.

Can any provide a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use CSS to set the size of the images in the slideshow without necessarily changing the aspect ratio of the image.

- set the height of the image to the height of the slideshow container
- make the width auto so it maintains its aspect ratio
- set a max-width so it doesn't get wider than the slideshow

```
slideshow.img{
    height:170px
    width:auto;/*maintain aspect ratio*/
    max-width:500px;
}
```

Note the images might be slimmer than the slideshow if the original size is small.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use CSS's `max-width` property. You won't want to specify the width or height if you do this.

Your HTML:

```
<div id="yourContainer">
    <img src="imagePath" />
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
#yourContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 170px;
}

#yourContainer img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

This won't centre your image inside of the container, but it should get the job done for you.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out how to accomplish image resize keeping aspect ratio and centering the image with simple piece of CSS code as follow:

```
width: auto !important; /*Keep the aspect ratio of the image*/
height: 140px !important;
margin: 0 auto 1em auto; /*Center the image*/
```

Hope this help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below combination of height and width

```
style="height:271px; max-height: 336px; max-width:336px; width: 263px;"
```